# Adjust sequence of attribute table of two shapefiles in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have two shapefiles (A and B). Each contain 200 polygons. I want to compare the area of each corresponding polygon. But the sequence of the polygons in each shapefile (A and B) is different. How can I arrange these polygons in order? For example the FID of a polygon in shapefile (A) is 1 but the FID of same polygon in shapefile (B) is 36.

Answer (score 1):

So the 200 polygons in "B" are exactly the same as polygons in "A" but in a different row order? Try using the [SORT](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) tool but sorting spatially. Then you can add a new ID field to both datasets and you can join/relate on that.